# Distribution of a ratio of two proportions

Tags: distributions, variance, binomial-distribution, proportion

$A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are positive integers.

$$A \sim Binomial(p_1, A+B)$$

$$A+C \sim Binomial(p_2, A+B+C+D)$$

My variable of interest is $p_1/p_2$

Could one analytically compute a distribution (preferably exact) for this variable? What would be its mean and variance (how to compute it?).

Comment: I've added the latex, but your question does not make sense. If $A$ is integer, how come it is also a random variable distributed with binomial distribution? And $p_1$ with $p_2$ are the parameters, i.e. not random variables, so their distribution is trivial. Perhaps you had in mind the estimates of these parameters?

Comment: Ok thanks but I really would like to know the distribution p1/p2; it would be in similar spirit to what they use as a distribution for the odds ratio or the risk ratio or the (log odds) to be able to estimate statistics of interest like its mean and variance, confidence intervals etc...

Comment: -1, for the reasons that @mpiktas has stated - $p_1$ and $p_2$ aren't random variables and haven't got distributions, and neither has $p_1/p_2$. I think there's an interesting question behind this though; perhaps if you gave us some more context we could help restate it properly.

Comment: It may help you to think of it as a random vector R = (r1, r2) with mean mu = (p1, p2). But I'll doubt anyone could come up with a better answer than Greg Snow gave below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a standard 2x2 table and you want to condition on the margins and compare the conditional proportion to the marginal proportion.  This is not simple theoretically since they are not going to be independent.  Someone has probably solved this problem sometime, probably in a thesis somewhere, but I have no idea where to look.

On the other hand, you con easily simulate to estimate the distribution and answer many questions using that.  If you want to condition on the margins and test the null that p1/p2=1 then this is just a simple permutation test:

Compute p1/p2, then randomly permute the A/B status of individual points and compute p1/p2 again, repeate a bunch of times and compare your original to the distribution.

If you want to see how your estimates of p1/p2 are distributed based on values of p1 and p2 with them unequal, then just simulate a bunch of times from binomials with the assumed p1 and p2 and do the computations.

Combining both of the above would show the power of the permutation test for a given alternative.

Comment: OK, the closest statistic I could find is called the [Location Quotient](http://biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/5/32). However they don't describe a pdf.